# Kubuntu 15.04 Plasma 5.3 showing KDE apps with GTK themes

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5

After upgrading to KDE 5.3 using Kubuntu Backports PPA, my system looks ugly with GTK themes overriding the default KDE Breeze themes, despite having all workspace and widget themes set to Breeze in system settings. Even the system settings manager itself and other dialogs are displayed with a GTK theme.

[image]
Which steps could I take to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=124931

put this

**export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=kde**

on your ~/.profile